# Why does this quit immediately on SIGKILL?

Tags: python, signals, interrupt

When I press Ctrl-C, the following code terminates immediately.

However, it seems that the loop should exit after a 10 second delay - because it is not checking the status of `keep_going` until we reach the top of the loop. Why is this code exiting the loop immediately?

How would I make sure that the loop finishes execution before exiting?

```
import signal
import time

keep_going = True

def signal_handler(signal, frame):
    global keep_going
    print 'quitting!'
    keep_going = False

signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, signal_handler) 

while keep_going:
    print 'looping...'
    time.sleep(10)
    print 'bye!'
```

Comment: What output do you get when it quits? BTW, that is SIGINT, but your question says SIGKILL.

Comment: `jay@coltrane ~ $ python t.py 
looping...
^Cquitting!
bye!`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [Python docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html#time.sleep):

> The actual suspension time may be less than that requested because any caught signal will terminate the sleep() following execution of that signal’s catching routine.

I.e. the loop does finish its execution (as you can see from the `"bye"` being output after the signal handler's `"quitting!"`), it's just `sleep` that is cut short.

If you had something more substantial than `sleep`, I believe you'd see what you originally wanted.

Answer (score 2):

The signal interrupts the sleep call, continues with the loop, the condition is False, so it terminates the loop. Python does not resume the sleep call.

BTW, the Python interpreter normally catches SIGINT itself, and translates that to a *KeyboardInterrupt* exception that you can catch instead of using the signal module.